# C++ Type Conversion Operator and Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory, operator-overloading, type-conversion, memory-leaks

I want to allow my Class1 to be convertible to Class2 by a type conversion operator:

```
class  Class1     {
public:
    operator Class2() const {
      //....
    }
}
```

But if I create a Class2 object in the operator implementation, very likely it will not get deleted by the caller.  So what is the best way to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There only needs to be deletion if you do something crazy like this:

```
operator Class2() const
{
    Class2 *p = new Class2();
    ...
    return *p;
}
```

However, the following is fine:

```
operator Class2() const
{
    Class2 c2;
    ...
    return c2;
}
```

Comment: Well, first snippet won't even compile as you're returning Class2* not Class2 itself.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was inattentive. Didn't notice dereference.

Comment: @Oli, +1, but I think its worth mentioning for the OP's benefit that in the first example, the memory is allocated in the free-store, so needs explicit deleting, but in the second its allocated on the stack, so `c2` gets released when `operator Class2()` returns, and a copy of it is passed to the caller.

Comment: What if I want to avoid the copying when returning C2 (the 2nd case)?

Comment: @JavaMan There probably isn't any copying; compilers are pretty good at omitting copies in that sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not allocate memory on the heap but make Class2 in the stack. Then it will be destroyed on function exit.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
operator Class2() const 
{
    Class2 tmp;
    ...
    return tmp;
}
```

Then if you have something like this

```
Class1 c1;
Class2 c2 = c1;
```

the memory for `tmp` will be allocated in stack, then a copy constructor of `Class2` would be called to copy `tmp` to `c2`, and then the destructor of `tmp` would be called as it is an automatic variable.